# Conventional way for calling a template function

Tags: c++, templates

```
struct A
{
    template <class U> 
    void f(U)
    {

    }
};

template <class T>
void f(T t) 
{
    A a;
    a.template f<int>(t);
    a.template f<>(t);
    a.f<int>(t);
    a.f<>(t);
    a.f(t);
}
```

At least under MSVC2010 the above code compile fine.

Among all the manners to call `A.f` is there any preferentials way to do this?

Is there any differences ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `a` has type `A`, which is not a dependent type in this context.  So the `template` keyword is not needed and only serves to obfuscate the code -- don't use it.

The version that invokes a template without supplying any arguments, again does nothing to change behavior and only makes the code less readable -- don't use it either.

Between the two remaining candidates, `a.f(t)` and `a.f<int>(t)`, use the first in most cases, and the second if the compiler fails to deduce the type.

Comment: If I have instead A<T> a, the first call becoming preferable ?

Comment: @Guillaume07: Not *preferable*, but *necessary* (if template arguments are explicitly supplied).  Otherwise the compiler would parse `a.f<int` as the less-than operator.

Answer (score 1):

The last one seems easiest to write.

Otherwise there are no differences, unless you have to disambiguate between several f's.

Answer (score 1):

No differences at all. If you don't have any reason to provide type information to the function, the last one is the best. But you may want your function to process arguments as if they are of the specified type, only then, should you need <>. For example

```
T Divide(T a, T b)
{
    return a/b;
}
```

If you call Divide(5,2), you get 2. Only cases like this, should you specify type:

```
Divide<float>(5,2);
```

It returns 2.5.